# how do you tell vba to go back up to an earlier line in your code

Tags: vba

how do you tell vba to go back up to an earlier line in your code. I'd imagine i need to use the GoTo command, but i'm not sure.

Comment: GOTO is usually frowned upon, if you present an example you will likely get an answer that uses a loop construction.

Comment: Why is GoTo frowned upon?

Comment: Because it can usually be replaced with loop constructions that offer greater clarity of intent and less possibility of error. Its subjective of course.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful

Comment: I agree that you should use a loop when appropriate but if you are simply wanting to skip a block of code if some condition exists then GoTo is a good way to do it.  It depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GOTO like so:

```
some code
...

if some exit condition goto label

more code that gets skipped
...

label:
exit routine
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work. Note that this is just an example. You should never use goto to accomplish what is being done here. A while loop would be better for example.

```
Sub gotoExample()
        Dim a As Integer
        a = 1
line1:
        a = a + 1
        If a < 10 Then
            GoTo line1
        End If
End Sub
```